# Rules for converting between pointer types where cv-qualifiers are the only difference

Tags: c++, constants, volatile, const-correctness, c++98

This question specifically relates to C++98, but feel free to pitch in any useful info w/regard to newer standards if you like.

In case you know the answer and want to skip the rest, the short & sweet of it is:

```
int **w;
int volatile*     *x = w; // error
int volatile*const*y = w; // OK
int const   *const*z = w; // OK
```

Why would `const` be necessary to the right of `volatile` in the declaration of `y`?  What possible evil could someone accomplish if the declaration for `x` were allowed?

In section *4.4.4* of the standard it says:

> A conversion can add cv-qualifiers **at levels other than the first** in multi-level pointers, subject to the following rules:
>
> Two pointer types T1 & T2 are *similar* if there exists a type T and integer *n* > 0 such that:
>
> - T1 is CV10 ptr to CV11 ptr to ... CV1N T
> - T2 is CV20 ptr to CV21 ptr to ... CV2N T
>
> ... where each CVij is const, volatile, const volatile, or nothing.  The n-tuple of cv-qualifiers **after** the first in a pointer type, e.g., CV11, CV12, ..., CV1N in the pointer type T1, is called the *cv-qualification signature* of the pointer type.  An expression of type T1 can be converted to type T2 **iff** the following conditions are satisfied:
>
> 1. the pointer types are similar
> 2. for every *j* > 0, if const is in CV1j, then const is in CV2j, and similarly for volatile.
> 3. if the CV1j and CV2j are different, then const is in every CV2k for *0 < k < j*

... after which it goes on to give an example for assigning a `**` to a `const**`.  The **emphasis** above is mine, italics are from the document.

Putting this into code:

```
 int CV13* CV12* CV11* CV10 b1;
 int CV23* CV22* CV21* CV20 b2 = b1;
```

I'm a little fuzzy on some of the details ... so here's some questions or potentially flawed observations:

1) It says `at levels other than the first`; this isn't elaborated on any further, but `CV20` can be any valid CV qualifier.

2) The 3rd rule at the bottom says if T2 adds either `const` OR `volatile` at level `j`, then levels `1 ... j-1` must be const (or suffer the wrath).  In the following, the # of stars differs from the one at the top to emphasize what the 3rd rule says:

```
int *****w;
int **volatile*     *     *x = w; // error
int **volatile*const*const*y = w; // OK
int **const   *const*const*z = w; // OK
```

I understand why it's needed for `z`, but why with `y`?  Here's roughly what the example in 4.4.4 looks like, modified for the volatile case:

```
void f( int **x ) {
  int volatile**y = x; // not allowed
  // do some evil here
}
```

What evil could be put there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Note: "This question specifically relates to C++98" but the state of affairs is the same in all versions of the Standard, past and present (and future too I would bet), because it's essentially about const-correctness and preventing coders from opening a hole in the type system.)

As the Standard uses the general term "*cv-qualifiers*", I find it easier to understand when reasoning only with "`const`" (no "`volatile`") *[but see further below for an example with `volatile`]*. The "C++ FAQ Lite" has a related entry : [Why am I getting an error converting a `Foo**` → `Foo const**`?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/constptrptr-conversion.html)

Essentially, allowing the conversion would let you silently modify a *const* T (through a pointer to *non*-const T):

```cpp
int const theAnswer = 42;
int* p = 0;  // int* p = &theAnswer; is not allowed of course...
int** pp = &p;
int const** ppc = pp;  // <-- Error, but imagine this were allowed...
*ppc = &theAnswer;  // &theAnswer is `int const*` and *ppc is `int const*` too,
                    // but it's also doing *pp = &theAnswer; i.e. p = &theAnswer;
*p = 999;  // I.e. theAnswer = 999; => modifying a const int!
```

But by adding a "first-level" `const`, the conversion `int const* const* pcpc = pp;` is valid because the compiler will prevent you doing `*pcpc = &theAnswer;` afterwards (because `*pcpc` is `const`).

---

*Edit:* As for `volatile`, the problem is maybe less obvious than with `const`, but allowing the conversion would let you silently incorrectly access (read or write) a *volatile* T as if it were *not* volatile (through a pointer to *non*-volatile T):

```cpp
extern int volatile externTimer;
int* p = 0;  // int* p = &externTimer; is not allowed...
int** pp = &p;
int volatile** ppv = pp;  // <-- Error, but imagine this were allowed...
*ppv = &externTimer;  // &externTimer is `int volatile*` and *ppv too,
                      // but it's also doing *pp = &externTimer; i.e. p = &externTimer;
int a1 = externTimer;  // First read
int a2 = externTimer;  // Second read, mandatory: the value may have changed externally
int b1 = *p;  // First read
int b2 = *p;  // Second read? may be optimized out! because *p is not volatile
```

But by adding a "first-level" `const`, the conversion `int volatile* const* pcpv = pp;` is valid because the compiler will prevent you doing `*pcpv = &externTimer;` afterwards (because `*pcpv` is `const`).